Remove backgroud Captcha Python r/Python
I have a question. I'm working on a project and I want to isolate just the letters from my captcha images. I want to remove the background and keep only the letters, but I have 300 images like this. How would I do that? All the methods I've tried haven't worked perfectly.
Captcha
I tried using this code, but it turned out terrible.
import cv2
from PIL import Image

metodos = [
    cv2.THRESH_BINARY,
    cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,
    cv2.THRESH_TRUNC,
    cv2.THRESH_TOZERO,
    cv2.THRESH_TOZERO_INV,
]

imagem = cv2.imread("bdcaptcha/captcha1.png")

imagem_cinza = cv2.cvtColor(imagem, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

i = 0
for metodo in metodos:
    i += 1
    _, imagem_tratada = cv2.threshold(
        imagem_cinza, 50, 255, metodo or cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    cv2.imwrite(f'testemetodos/imagem_tratada_{i}.png', imagem_tratada)

imagem = Image.open("testemetodos/imagem_tratada_3.png")
imagem = imagem.convert("P")
imagem2 = Image.new("P", imagem.size, (255, 255, 255))

for x in range(imagem.size[1]):
    for y in range(imagem.size[0]):
        cor_pixel = imagem.getpixel((y, x))
        if cor_pixel < 115:
            imagem2.putpixel((y, x), (0, 0, 0))

imagem2.save('testemetodos/imagemfinal.png')


